# Custom controls in a row of a list view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, datatemplate

I want a list view control (or any list like control) in which each row (item), not only has text, but also some other controls. For example, each row (item) in my list view is composed of a checkbox, button, a slider, a image and a label. I tried the corresponding renderer classes (CheckBox renderer) in the owner drawn event, but i am not able to handle the events (as they are just used to render the control on the screen).

I tried to search for solutions, but in vain. So I have decided to have a panel and then create objects of those controls in runtime, for each item and add it to the parent panel. Is the solution ok? I feel this to be process costly. Help me out !!

Note, *I am using WinForms and no DataTemplates or WPF stuffs*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/extendedlistviews.aspx